# Is there a way to prevent new OSes from being installed over the current OS?

Tags: bios, operating-systems, anti-theft

I'm trying to make it easier to recover my laptop in case of theft. I already have Prey installed to give me my laptop's location. However, anyone can easily install a new OS, rendering Prey useless.

Is there a way to require a password to install a new OS? I have a Lenovo Thinkpad.

Comment: Some hdd hardware supports look for hardware which supports encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indirectly, yes by messing with bios settings and monkeywrenching any other boot device options.

You can set the boot order in bios on my x220 I hit <kbd>del</kbd> to go to the bios, then select the startup menu

In "boot" you can *disable* devices by pressing ! (so you can change it later). Disable *everything* but your boot device. *Disable* the boot device list option and use boot order lock so no one can change it

Then switch to the security menu

There set a password so that no one else can alter your bios settings.

There may also be specific, bios level security options worth looking at there, but your mileage may vary

In theory this would make it hard to *casually* change your boot device, and pulling your hard drive and installing a new one wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You basically can't, since if you encrypt the disk it will be anyway repartitioned by a new os install and bios passwords are easily removable by removing the cmos battery or by special programs. The only way would be to  permanently physically attach the drive to the laptop and make it read only, but this will make the os useless.

Answer (score 0):

Journeyman Geek's answer is correct.  There is no foolproof way of doing it but many newer laptops (Dell for example) have their BIOS passwords protected by a capacitor that retains the password even if you pull the battery.  They are very difficult to bypass and require you to contact the vendor and show proof of ownership before they will help you to recover it.  For this very reason, don't forget your password!

Answer (score -1):

you can do hardware level disc encryption which encrypts your entire hard drive separately from anything else in the computer. Another option, which I know that the federal government uses (source: my father works for them) is a pre operating system encryption system that prevents all access to the main hard drive partition unless it is unlocked. This would probably be your best bet.

TL;DR: use pre OS disc encryption.

Comment: Isn't disc encryption used to protect my data? Can't they just delete everything and install a new OS?

Comment: This would only prevent them from seeing the data. Nothing to stop them writing over the top of it.

Comment: I think it even bypasses the bios so it starts up first, but I am not certain.